# Significado de "hemeralopía" opuesto al etimológico

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, historia, vocabulario-médico

El Diccionario de la Lengua define [**hemeralopía**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K86EQY7) como

> Del lat. cient. *hemeralopia*, y este del gr. *ἡμεράλωψ*, *-ωπος* *hēmerálōps*, *-ōpos* '**ciego de día**' y el lat. *-ia* *'-ia'*. 
>   1. f. Med. **Pérdida de visión cuando la iluminación es escasa.**

Etimológicamente era, por tanto, "ceguera durante el día" = "mala visión cuando la iluminación es abundante" y ha adquirido el significado opuesto: "mala visión cuando la iluminación es escasa" = "ceguera nocturna"

El "Diccionario terminológico de ciencias médicas" (Salvat, 1982) define hemeralopía com:

> (del gr. *hemera*, día, *alaós*, ciego, y *ops, opós*, ojo) f. A., Término equívoco que aunque etimológicamente significa falta de aptitud para ver a pleno día, se emplea en sentido contrario o sea de disminución de la agudeza visual a la luz crepuscular o poco intensa"

¿Cómo se produjo este cambio al significado opuesto?

Answer (score 1):

Pues parece que el cambio se produjo cuando la RAE posiblemente erró con la etimología de la palabra. Según algunos diccionarios registrados en el NTLLE, como el Zerolo de 1895, la palabra proviene del griego, sí, pero de un modo diferente al que dicen: asegura que la primera parte de la palabra (ἡμέρα, *heméra*) significa simplemente "día", y la parte final viene de βλέπω (*vlépo*, ver) y significa simplemente "yo veo". Por tanto, la "hemeralopía" sería simplemente "yo veo de día" o "visión diurna".

En griego antiguo, "ciego" se decía τυφλός (*tuflós*), que no aparece en la palabra completa.

Otra opción sería que la palabra proviniera de ἡμέρα (*heméra*, día), ὄψις (*ópsis*, visión, vista), y en medio se colara ὅλος (*holos*, único, solamente): visión solo de día.