# Significados contradictorios de "nictálope"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, etimología, vocabulario-médico, curiosidades

El Dicionario de la Lengua da para [**nictálope**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QU6veUi) únicamente dos definiciones que además son contradictorias, se utilizan en el mismo ámbito y no se indica que una de las dos sea desusada o preferida:

> 1. adj. Biol. y Med. Dicho de una persona o especialmente de un animal: **Que ve mejor de noche que de día.** U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Biol. y Med. Dicho especialmente de una persona: **Que tiene dificultad para ver de noche o con luz escasa.** U. t. c. s.

Parece que el problema viene de antiguo, ya que el propio Diccionario de la Lengua indica en la [etimología](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QU6veUi) de la palabra que

> Del lat. *nyctălops, -ōpis* '**que solo ve de noche**', y este del gr. *νυκτάλωψ, -ωπος nyktálōps, -ōpos* '**que no ve de noche**'

Por otro lado, consultando el "Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico", aparece en la entrada más antigua de "nictalope" (1787 TERREROS Y PANDO)

> Segun Plinio es el que **de dia ve bastantemente, por la tarde poco, y de noche nada**, lo cual se conforma con la Nictalopia; pero eso no obstante lo explican otros diciendo, que el Nictalope es el que **de noche ve bastante, y de dia es ciego**. Teodor. Prisc. l. 1.c.10

El "Diccionario terminológico de ciencias médicas" (Salvat, 1982) define **nictálope** como:

> (del gr. *nyx, nyktós*, noche, *alaós*, ciego, y *ops, opós*, ojo). adj. Dícese de la persona afecta de nictalopía.

y **nictalopía** como

> Ceguera nocturna o visión imperfecta con luz escasa; con este significado sería sinónimo de *hemeralopía* tal y como hoy se entiende este último término (V. HEMERALOPÍA); pero, en general, *nictalopía* significa precisamente lo contrario de lo que indica su etimología: visión mejor con luz escasa que con luz brillante.

¿Cómo pueden persistir hasta hoy esas dos acepciones contradictorias? ¿Se utiliza con ambas acepciones, o el uso habitual es con una de ellas y la otra no se utiliza?

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo desde [la respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18718/12637) a la anterior pregunta, la palabra vendría de νύξ (*nýx*, noche) y βλέπω (*vlépo*, ver). O puede que venga de νύξ (*nýx*, noche), ὄψις (*ópsis*, visión, vista), y en medio se colara ὅλος (*holos*, único, solamente): visión solo de noche. Lo curioso es que si buscas en el [fichero general](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) de la RAE la palabra "hemeralopía", en muchas de las tarjetas simplemente te redirigen a "nictalopía", aumentando la confusión. Sin embargo, en uno de los diccionarios del NTTLE, el Domínguez de 1853, se lee lo siguiente:

> Algunos dicen que esta palabra designa una afección en la cual uno está privado de vista durante la noche; pero esto no deja de ser un error gramatical y un contrasentido.

Se suele usar para designar a esas aves que tienen mejor visión durante la noche:

> Habían resurgido los conocidos monstruos, con la misma imprecisión de las pesadillas, pero también con su misma potencia, encabezados por la ambigua figura de costumbre, que desde la oscuridad lo observaba con sus ojos verdosos, con su mirada de nictálope, la expresión de una nocturna ave de rapiña.
>
> - Ernesto Sábato, "Abaddón el exterminador", Argentina (1974)

Ahora bien, recordemos que la RAE únicamente se dedica a recoger la expresión escrita, y ha habido muchos casos en los que las palabras "hemerálope" y "nictálope" se han usado indistintamente, debido la confusión que ambas palabras causan. ¿Cuál es la que designa al que no ve de día y cuál al que no ve de noche? Si no se conoce la etimología es fácil confundirlas, como hay mucha gente que confunde los términos "miope" e "hipermétrope" (no saben cuál es el que ve de cerca y cuál el que ve de lejos). Por eso existen ambos sentidos en el diccionario. Ahora bien, lo que no veo lógico es que la RAE aumente la confusión al incluir etimologías contradictorias. No es que yo diga que la que yo presento sea correcta, pero al menos que lo investiguen más concienzudamente, ya que hay autores que durante los años han parecido discrepar.